# Accessing attributes inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I'm doing a fetch inside my componentDidMount as follows

```
componentDidMount() {

        fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA', {
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data)=>{

            console.log(data);
            });

    }
```

And my console outputs the data as follows

```
{response: {…}}
response:
docs: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
maxScore: 6.3768473
numFound: 5026
start: 0
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

I want to access the docs array here. I've tried `console.log(data.docs);` but it returns an undefined. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried with `data.response.docs`?

Answer (score 2):

You should try =>

console.log(data.response.docs);